# Can I use prometheus to count all emails sent by django server in one day?

Tags: django, prometheus

Actually this is the question. How could I implement this? 
django-prometheus                        2.1.0
prometheus-client                        0.8.0
django                                   2.2.17

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, to which the answer is probably "yes, but it feels like overkill unless you're already using prometheus". Are you?

Comment: yeah, it used on the project ;)